# Is there a way to save checkbox state when server-side processing pagination occurs in DataTables?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatables

I have a table like this:
[image]

There are some checkboxes checked. When I go to the lets say second page, and return back to first one(on which i checked checkboxes) they are unchecked. I understand that new data are being drawn and that state will be lost, but I wonder is there a way to order `DataTable` to save that state? I tried putting `"StateSave": true` when initiate `DataTable` but that seems to be wrong method for doing this. Any idea?

Comment: how do you manage the change of each checkbox? What are they for?

Comment: I don't think there's an official `Datatables` way of doing this, but one way to do this is to store the clicked row id's in an array.  [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/abhbs4x8/) is an example.